# "zf create controller" not creating PHPUnit tests

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

Not quite sure why I'm not able to create PHPUnit tests automatically when I create a new Zend controller.

I'm working on Windows with XAMPP. I've installled PHPunit via pear and it's recognized in the command line (version 3.5.14)

The include_path in the php.ini contains c:\xampp\php\PEAR;c:\ZendFramework\library

I added this c:\ZendFramework\library as well to my PATH and ZEND_TOOL_INCLUDE_PATH variables.

But still when I create a new controller, no test cases are created with the following message:

```
Note: PHPUnit is required in order to generate controller test stubs.
```

Any idea of something I'm missing or I could try please?

Comment: Is the `phpunit.bat` executable script on your path?

Comment: Yes, the command line recognizes 'phpunit' ('phpunit.bat') and the following folders are included under the c:\xampp\php\PEAR directory which is added to my PATH:

PHPUnit  folder
PHPUnit2 folder

Comment: Do you mean you have two PHPUnit folders, one with a 2 at the end?

Comment: Yes, not sure how they were created, but they've got different content.

PHPUnit2 has just got 5 folders (Extensions, Framework, Runner, TextUI, Util)

whereas PHPUnit has the folders above as well as another GUI folder and then 11 files (Assert.php, Autoload.php, Framework.php, RepeatedTest.php, Skeleton.php, TestCase.php, TestDecorator.php, TestFailure.php, TestListener.php, TestResult.php, TestSuite.php)

It's still not working from the command line although I've now seen that it's working when creating the controllers from inside Netbeans :S

Comment: That second folder you listed looks either very old or very broken. I would start by creating a simple test and getting it to run in PHPUnit from the command line. The unit test skeletons are created by PHPUnit for zftool.

Comment: Try this http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=69&p=76028#p67328

Comment: I'll try that when I get home, but do you know which path should I add to which file? Xampp in windows doesn't have this structure ('bin\apache\Apache\bin'), and I don't remember any php.ini file inside the Apache folder, just under the php folder...

Comment: Still nothing!, I've added "C:\xampp\php\PEAR\PHPUnit" to my php.ini file and still nothing... receiving the same error message? No idea what could be going on...